# PHP - count array based other array (array('a','d')=array('d','a'))

Tags: php, arrays

**I have array like this:**

```
$array1 = array(Array('a','d'), 
                Array('c','a'),
                Array('d','a'),
                Array('a','b','c','d','e'),  
                 );

$array2 = array(array('a','d'), array('a','b','c','d','e')) ;
$result = array();
```

**Here's my code:**

```
    foreach ($array2 as $part) {
        $key = implode(', ', $part);
        if( ! array_key_exists ($key, $array1)) {
            $result[$key] = 0;
        }
        $result[$key] = $result[$key] + 1;
    }
    foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
        echo "$value of {$key}<br/>";   
    }
```

I want to count values `$array2` based on `$array1`
I got this one:

```
1 of a,d
1 of a,b,c,d,e
```

But I want a result like this:

```
3 of a,d
1 of a,b,c,d,e
```

If anybody wonders why there's (3 of a,d), it count from `array('a','d')`, `array('d','a')` also counted as `array('a','d')` and `array('a','b','c','d','e')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Here is a working demo https://eval.in/117810

```
<?
$array1 = array(array('a','d'), 
                array('c','a'),
                array('d','a'),
                array('a','b','c','d','e'),  
               );

$array2 = array(array('a','d'), array('a','b','c','d','e')) ;
$result = array();

foreach ($array2 as $key=>$part2) {
    sort($part2);
    if(!isset($result[$key]))$result[$key]=0;
    foreach($array1 as $part1) {
        $intersect = array_intersect($part1, $part2);
        sort($intersect);
        if ($intersect === $part2) {
            $result[$key]++;
        }
    }
}

foreach($result as $k=>$v) {
    echo $v . " of " . implode(',', $array2[$k]) . "<br/>"; 
}

?>
```

Comment: i got this Notice: Undefined offset: 0 and Notice: Undefined offset: 1,, why??

Comment: On which line? Also this is a notice when you try to print an array item which does not exist

Comment: at `$result[$key]++;`
i've tried copy-paste your code, i got the same thing

Comment: I have added a line inside the first `foreach` loop `if(!isset($result[$key]))$result[$key]=0;`. This will get rid of the `notice`

Comment: SajithNair please help again, when i change $array2 =  `array('c','a')` and `array('d','a') it got 0.. why?? it should count by 2 of c,a and 3 of d,a

Comment: Looks like we need to add one more line inside first `foreach`. I have updated my answer and added line `sort($part2);`. Please see new working example with the new values https://eval.in/119217